# How find vector v in this question?

Tags: linear-algebra

Q. The coordinate vector if a vector $v$ with respect to an orthonormal bases $B$ = {$v_1$, $v_2$} of $R^2$ is [$v$]$_B$ =(-3, 1/2). If $v_1$ = (3/5 , 4/5), find all possible vectors $v$.

Comment: Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Im korean, my english skill very fool. sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give some "geometric" hints. Since $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is orthonormal you know two things about $v_2$. Its length is equal to 1 and it is vertical to $v_1$. Draw the shape and I hope you will see that there are only two possible vectors that can form an orthonormal base with $v_1$.

Each one leads to a specific vector $v$.

For comparison (1,0) can form an orthonormal base only with vector (0,1) or with vector (0,-1).